# PHP.ini Ponderism setting conflict with declare strict_types

Tags: php, performance, installation

Confusion has arisen...

Declaring strict_types followed by ini_set("display_errors", 1); produces warnings stating the second parameter should be a string.

Setting the php.ini setting default to On and echoing ini_get("display_errors"); displays 1 but no declare strict types warning?

Setting the PHP.ini display_errors "true" and echoing ini_get("display_errors"); displays true.

Does this mean that if the second parameter is set to an integer type juggling will be enforced and influence performance?

Comment: None of this is relevant to performance. Start looking around [basic_functions.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L5507) if you think it worth investigating.

Answer (score 0):

On the manual page about the ini settings (http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) all values are set to strings (or numerics) besides of NULL values. String values "true", "on" and "yes" are converted to TRUE. "false", "off", "no" and "none" are considered FALSE. "null" is converted to NULL in typed mode. Also, all numeric strings are converted to integer type if it is possible (http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)

If PHP does it internally, the performance drop won't be visible.